# Send data to server on changing preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences, application-settings

I am trying to use the Preferences api to create a settings screen for my application , I am using some EditTextPreference to change some settings but I want to send them to the server as soon as I click ok from the dialog screen , is that possible ?? how to do it please?

Note: I know how to send data to the server I just want to know where can I control the dialog pressed button.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of screen do you use that it has an ok button?

Comment: I am using the default preference screen and am using EditTextPreference  as I stated above and how it works is when you click on it it prompts you to a dialog where you enter a new string and then click ok , that is the ok button I wanna handle or at least the data changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement

```
 public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {
}
```

if you first register an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`.

```
 public class Prefs extends PreferenceActivity implements
    OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
            .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```

You will find better examples if you search this site.